# Как сделать косые блоки?

Tags: css3, html5

У меня есть макет сайта(нашел в инете), на этом макете косые блоки и фотографии сразу на двух блоках, как такое сделать? html, css[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство clip-path хорошо справляется в таких случаях

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  background-color: rgb(106, 155, 242);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 70%, 0 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff2a3d, #fe4835, #fc5e2e, #fa7029, #f68127);
}
```

```html
<section><section>
```

Comment: `clip-path` не поддерживается ни `IE` ни `Edge`

Comment: @Air Ну не будет скоса в ie, будет стандартный прямоугольник, это проблема? В 2018 году равняться на ие в таких мелочах это педантство.  Разве что если есть требование в поддержке ie, тогда нужно svg использовать

Comment: Так это просто секция косая, а на макете блок делится на две части оранжевую и белую. Как это сделать?

Comment: @МатвейСамохин добавить белый фон например